# is it possible to resize 480x640 to 480x1270 with perfect image quality

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I resized an image using photoshop. But the quality of picture doesn't looks good.
Is it possible to resize a image size 480x640 to 480x1270 with best pixel quality?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Please note that your question does not have a single valid answer and is primarily based on opinions. Also what do you mean with _best pixel quality_? Scaling images always have the problem with quality loss.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you mean by best pixel quality.

Enlarging an image means more pixels will be shown. Pixels that previously weren't there. Because the pixels weren't there, Photoshop has to guess what the pixels are going to be.

In your case I would resize the image from 480x640 to 480x1280 which is double the pixels, and use `Nearest Neighbor (preserve hard edges)` as resize image option.

This will basically copy the pixel to its left which usually gives the best visual appearance. (otherwise it always will appear washed out).

You can now try to resize from 480x1280 to 480x1270 using `Bicubic Sharper (best for reduction)` as resize image option, but this might make things look worse than they are.

If the image however has thin lines, these will clearly show pixels though, but the reducing might actually provide the smooth required to fix this. You can try using one of the other bicubic options when reducing the image to see if they assist in getting a better output.

But that's basically the option you have. Image editors just cannot see patterns like humans do and enlarge thin lines with perfect quality. They can use an average of pixel colors from the 2 pixels it is going to be in between, but that always gives a blurry image. With a photo where colors flow naturally into eachother, that is not a problem, but with high contrasts, you easily get quality loss.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using vector graphics as e.g. SVG, it's not possible. There are just not enough information avaialble.